# Weird bug with addresses

Tags: c++, c, windows

I have a couple problems to solve, please help!

My first problem was **expression must be a pointer to a complete object type** but I have solved that by adding **&** before variable, do I did it right?

Fragment of a code below.

```
    LPVOID dll;
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dos;
    dll = LoadLibraryA(a[1]);
    dos = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)dll;
    nt = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)(&dll+dos->e_lfanew);
```

Next problem is that my program is outputting always different, why?
My program should show me all addresses and name of functions, code below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<winternl.h>


int main(int i, char* a[]) {
    LPVOID dll, faddr;
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dos;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS nt;
    PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY exp;

    PWORD f_addr_list, f_name_list;
    PWORD f_ord_list;
    DWORD rva;
    LPSTR fname;


    if (i != 2) {
        printf("error");
        return 0;
    }

    dll = LoadLibraryA(a[1]);
    if (dll == NULL) {
        printf("failed to load");
        return 0;
    }

    dos = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)dll;
    nt = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)(dll+dos->e_lfanew);
    exp = (PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)(&dll + nt->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[0].VirtualAddress);

    f_addr_list = (PDWORD)(&dll + exp->AddressOfFunctions);
    f_name_list = (PDWORD)(&dll + exp->AddressOfNames);
    f_ord_list = (PWORD)(&dll + exp->AddressOfNameOrdinals);
    
    printf("Total function names: %ld\nTotal Function: %ld\n", exp->NumberOfNames, exp->NumberOfFunctions);
    printf("Address\t\t\t\t\Function Name\n");
    printf("-------\t\t\t\t\t----------\n");

    for (i = 0; i < exp->NumberOfNames; i++)
    {
        fname = (LPSTR)dll + f_name_list[i];
        rva = f_ord_list[i];
        faddr = &dll + f_addr_list[rva];
        printf("%p\t\t\t\t%s\n", faddr, fname);


    }

    FreeLibrary(dll);
    return 0;

}
```

**Example outputs:**

```
C:\Users\user\Project2\Debug>Project2.exe user32.dll
Total function names: 2
Total Function: 11914128
Address                         Function Name
-------                                 ----------

C:\Users\user\Project2\Debug>Project2.exe user32.dll
Total function names: 2
Total Function: 11914128
Address                         Function Name
-------                                 ----------

C:\Users\user\Project2\Debug>Project2.exe user32.dll
Total function names: 22826784
Total Function: 2
Address                         Function Name
-------                                 ----------
```

What's wrong in there?

Comment: `&dll+dos->e_lfanew` causes undefined behaviour . Generally speaking, "try things until the error goes away" is not a good way to program in C

Comment: Also please do not dual tag; select either C or C++ according to which sort of compiler you are using

Answer (score 2):

Under WIN OS the module handle **is the base address of library** as loaded in memory.

Adding the `&` before the address **don't solve the problem**, but creates a bigger one adding an indirection that leads to memory violation (now you're using the address of the variable `dll` as module base address).

You can't do math on void pointers, because a `void` haven't a size preventing the correct displacement calculation. Make your base pointer a `BYTE` pointer instead giving a base size of 1.

The working code for what you were trying to do is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<winternl.h>

int main(int i, char *a[])
{
    LPVOID faddr;
    BYTE *dll;
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dos;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS nt;
    PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY exp;

    PDWORD f_addr_list, f_name_list;
    PWORD f_ord_list;
    DWORD rva;
    LPSTR fname;

    if (i != 2)
    {
        printf("error\n");
        return 0;
    }

    dll = (BYTE *)LoadLibraryA(a[1]);
    if (dll == NULL)
    {
        printf("failed to load\n");
        return 0;
    }

    dos = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)dll;
    nt  = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS) (dll + dos->e_lfanew);
    exp = (PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY) (dll + nt->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[0].VirtualAddress);

    f_addr_list = (PDWORD) (dll + exp->AddressOfFunctions);
    f_name_list = (PDWORD) (dll + exp->AddressOfNames);
    f_ord_list  = (PWORD) (dll + exp->AddressOfNameOrdinals);

    printf("Total function names: %ld\nTotal Function: %ld\n", exp->NumberOfNames, exp->NumberOfFunctions);
    printf("Address\t\t\t\tFunction Name\n");
    printf("-------\t\t\t\t\t----------\n");

    for (i = 0; i < exp->NumberOfNames; i++)
    {
        fname = (LPSTR)(dll + f_name_list[i]);
        rva   = f_ord_list[i];
        faddr = dll + f_addr_list[rva];
        printf("%p\t\t\t\t%s\n", faddr, fname);
    }

    FreeLibrary((LPVOID)dll);
    return 0;

}
```